# Isn't the sum of a series of integers always an integer? (Stroustrup PPP - Chapter 5, Question 9)

Tags: c++

**Question 9:**

> Modify the program from exercise 8 to write out an error if the result cannot be represented as an int.

To give more context to question 9, here's **Question 8:**

> Write a program that reads and stores **a series of integers** and then computes the sum of the first N integers. First ask for N, then read the values into a vector, then calculate the sum of the first N values.

So my question is:

> **If I have a vector of integers, and I sum the elements in the vector, won't my result always be an integer? If so, what is question 9 in Stroustrup PPP asking for?**

*if it helps, [here's a link](https://github.com/lardandweed/Programming-Principles_and_Practice_Using_Cpp/blob/master/Chapter%205/Chapter%205%20Exercises/Ex_05.08.cpp) to my code for question 8.

Comment: Presumably it's asking if the value exceeds the [numeric_limits](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/numeric_limits)

Answer (score 5):

Yes, the result will always be an integer, but it may not be the "correct" solution because there was an **overflow**.

For instance if your integer type can only represent from -3 to 4, and you sum 2 and 3, what's the correct result? 5, but your integer result could be -3 instead (assuming 2-complement signed integers). That's what you need to detect.

Just an indication for the solution. `numeric_limits<T>::max()` is the max you can represent. If your current sum is `sum` and the new value `value`, what can you say about `max - value` and `sum` with regard to the overflow?

Comment: ah ic. In which case I cannot simply do a "if (sum > numeric_limits<int>::max()) ..." because if it overflows, sum just becomes some negative int right?

Comment: Exactly, you need to do something more. Some hint in my updated answer.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks a lot!

Comment: **signed** overflow is UB, so `5 == -3` is just one possible outcome of UB.

Comment: yes, but in the realm of integers from -3 to 4, that's what happens. The UB relates to 1-complement over 2-complement. On a specific architecture, the behavior is precisely defined.

Comment: We don't have code in the question, so I can't say for certain what wrap-around behavior we have. But either the integers are `signed` (in which case the overflow is Undefined Behavior, and must be avoided - no detection possible) or the integers are `unsigned` and then this answer's suggestion about negative answers does not make sense.

Comment: I added a note. The behavior may be called undefined with signed integers, but if you know that you have signed 2-complement, then it's perfectly well defined. It's just not part of the C++ standard, but part of digital electronics. But that's not the point, in both cases, you can detect an overflow by checking the value of the sum, the max and the next value.

Comment: The fact it is UB allows compiler to do simplification such as `a + c < b + c` -> `a < b` (valid for signed whereas invalid for unsigned), so even knowing target "architecture" doesn't guaranty behavior.

Answer (score 3):

Indeed mathematically speaking the set of integers is closed under addition.

But the `int` of C++ is bound by `numeric_limits<int>::min()` and `numeric_limits<int>::max()`. The behaviour on exceeding this range is undefined.

Comment: I understand the problem now. Cheers!

Answer (score 3):

> If I have a vector of integers, and I sum the elements in the vector, won't my result always be an integer?

It will be an integer, yes. But being an integer doesn't necessarily mean that it can be represented by `int`. You see, `int` has a limited range of numbers that it can represent. The task is to find out whether the result is within that range.

Comment: Got it! Thanks!

Comment: The tricky part of this task is that you need to find out if the answer is in range, _before_ trying to calculate the answer.